# Usar en Facades\DB desde blade en LAravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Estoy usando Laravel 5.8 y quisiera saber si hay una alternativa a usar Facades\DB desde la plantilla blade.
Por ejemplo desde el controlador envio al blade la variable

```
$proyectos = DB::table('proyectos')->get();
```

muestro su información en una tabla pero necesito obtener las **reclamaciones** asociadas a cada proyecto, me es imposible hacerlo desde el controlador puesto que necesito acceder a cada proyecto, así que lo logreé haciéndolo de la siguiente forma

```
<span class="d-none">
      {{
      $reclamaciones = DB::table('reclamaciones')
       ->where('reclamaciones.proyecto_id', $proyecto-> proyecto_id )
       ->get()
       }}
   </span>
```

Así por cada renglón de la tabla que contiene un proyecto  obtengo  sus reclamaciones. 
Mi pregunta es que tan buena o mala práctica es usar  Facades\DB desde la plantilla blade? 
y si es una mala práctica 
qué alternativa existe para estos casos  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deberás entonces trabajar con las relaciones de Laravel que te ofrecen **`Eloquent`**:

- `belongsTo`
- `hasMany`

De modo que tengas un par de modelos:

- Proyecto
- Reclamación

Así dentro de `Proyecto`, estableces el uso de `hasMany` para indicar que un proyecto puede tener varios registros de reclamaciones asociados:

```
class Proyecto extends Model
{
    public function reclamaciones()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Reclamacion::class);
    }
}
```

Idealmente dentro de tu modelo `Reclamacion`, usa `belongsTo` para indicar que varias reclaraciones pertenecen a un Proyecto:

```
class Reclamacion extends Model
{
    public function proyecto()
    {
         return $this->belongsTo(Proyecto::class);
    }
}
```

Ahora si lo que tratas es de recuperar un proyecto con todas sus reclamaciones, en tu controlador **`Proyecto`** deberías hacer esto:

```
$proyecto = Proyecto::with('reclamaciones')->find($id);
```

Lo siguiente *sería lo único que necesites para agregar en tu vista*, iterar y obtener los datos de un proyecto y todas sus reclamaciones.

**Consulta si usas el método `find()`**

```
{{ $proyecto->tituloProyecto }}
@foreach($proyecto->reclamaciones as $reclamacion)
    {{ $reclamacion->titulo }}
@endforeach
```

- Para obtener los datos del proyecto aquí no hace falta iterar pues la consulta no te devuelve una colección
- Donde si debes iterar es con el *posible* conjunto de reclamaciones que vengan asociadas a dicho proyecto
- Solo sustituye `tituloProyecto` y `titulo` por los nombres que correspondan a tus columnas de cada tabla.

O bien si deseas traer todos los proyectos y sus reclamaciones entonces solo cambia `find()` por `get()` para que te retorne una colección de registros.

```
$proyecto = Proyecto::with('reclamaciones')->get();
```

**Referencias**

- [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)
- [Relationships Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)
- [Laravel Models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#defining-models)

Answer (score 0):

Deberías utilizar modelos para hacerlo más fácil y en el modelo hacer la relación, yo lo haría de la siguiente forma:

Modelo Proyectos

```
php artisan make:model Proyectos
```

Modelo Reclamaciones

```
php artisan make:model Reclamaciones
```

en el modelo proyectos que se crea en la ruta app > Proyectos creas tu relación

```
public function reclamaciones() {
   $this->hasMany(Reclamaciones::class, 'proyecto_id', 'proyecto_id');
}
```

en el controlador traes todos tus proyectos a una variable de la siguiente forma

```
$proyectos = Proyectos::all();
```

en la plantilla suponiendo que tienes en tu tabla reclamaciones descripcion e reclamacion_id podemos acceder a estos atributos de la siguiente manera para representarlos en una tabla

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <th>
         <td>Id</td>
         <td>Descripcion</td>
      </th>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      @foreach($proyectos as $proyecto)
         @foreach($proyecto->recomendaciones as $recomendacion)
            <tr>
               <td>{{ $recomendacion->id }}</td>
               <td>{{ $recomendacion->descripcion }}</td>
            </tr>
         @endforeach
      @endforeach
   </tbody>
</table>
```

si no necesitas hacer doble foreach puedes hacer la relación inversa definiendo la relación en el modelo recomendaciones pero en lugar de hasMany vas a usar belongsTo.

si necesitas más ayuda no dudes en preguntar. Saludos